Create a conditional variable for incomplete data
Attached data:
id = c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
vm = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23")
GE = c("0", "0", "0", "0" "0", "0", "1", "0", "1","0")
fichier <- data.frame(id, vm, GE)

Attached R code:
library(tidyverse)
fichier <- fichier %>%
mutate(statut = case_when(
  fichier$vm == 13 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 14 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 15 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 16 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 17 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 19 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 20 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 21 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 22 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  fichier$vm == 23 & fichier$GE == 1 ~ "infection",
  TRUE ~ "noinfection")
)

Attached Results:
id = c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
vm = c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), 
GE = c("0", "0", "0", "0" "0", "0", "1", "0", "1","0"), 
statut = c("noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infecton", "noinfection")
fichier <- data.frame(id, vm, GE, status)

Please, I would like to be able to complete "status" variable at vm = 18 and vm = 24.
a) I would like to give this variable at vm = 18
- the value 0 if GE = 0 during the previous visits of 13 to 17.
- the value 1 if GE = 1 during the previous visits of 13 to 17.
b) I would like to give this variable at vm = 24
- the value 0 if GE = 0 during the previous visits of 19 to 23.
- the value 1 if GE = 1 during the previous visits of 19 to 23.

what have you tried? StackOverflow helps answer questions others may have, it's not just a free code writing service

it would be great if you could explain what the attached r code is for!

I could make something very very specific to these values (i.e. 18 and 24), but without knowing the underlying reasons for the things you are asking, it's hard to know if I'm actually giving you a good solution

Hello, thank you for your answers !
Previously, I showed the R code that I used to define the infected/uninfected status for certain visits (no problem for those).

But specifically for the 18 and 24 month visits, I need to create a variable taking into account the data from previous visits. And for this I can't find any R codes. Do you have any idea for this?

What specific solution do you have for these values (i.e. 18 and 24) ?

I see two potential scenarios in your description:

"status" for 18 == 0 and 24 == 1 as at least one previous GE value == 1 within set timeframe for 24
"status" for 18 == 0 and 24 == NA as not all previous GE values within set timeframe for 24 were the same

Either way, I have added solutions for both scenarios.
Load required packages and your data:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Your sample data
id <- c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
vm <- c("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23")
GE <- c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1","0")

fichier <- data.frame(id, vm, GE)

Scenario 1:
# Add missing data if all previous visit == 0 or any previous visits == 1
fichier <- fichier |>
  mutate(across(c(vm, GE), as.integer)) |>
  group_by(id) |> # assuming your data may have multiple id values
  complete(vm = 13:24) |>
  fill(id, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(tmp = if_else(vm <= 18, 1, 2)) |>
  group_by(id, tmp) |>
  mutate(GE = case_when(is.na(GE) & sum(GE, na.rm = TRUE) == 0 ~ 0,
                          is.na(GE) & sum(GE, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ 1,
                          .default = GE),
         status = if_else(GE == 1, "infection", "noinfection")) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-tmp)

fichier
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#       id    vm    GE status     
#    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>      
#  1     2    13     0 noinfection
#  2     2    14     0 noinfection
#  3     2    15     0 noinfection
#  4     2    16     0 noinfection
#  5     2    17     0 noinfection
#  6     2    18     0 noinfection
#  7     2    19     0 noinfection
#  8     2    20     1 infection  
#  9     2    21     0 noinfection
# 10     2    22     1 infection  
# 11     2    23     0 noinfection
# 12     2    24     1 infection

Scenario 2:
# Add missing data if all previous visit == 0 or all previous visits == 1
fichier <- fichier |>
  mutate(across(c(vm, GE), as.integer)) |>
  group_by(id) |> # assuming your data may have multiple id values
  complete(vm = 13:24) |>
  fill(id, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(tmp = if_else(vm <= 18, 1, 2)) |>
  group_by(id, tmp) |>
  mutate(tmp1 = +(n_distinct(GE, na.rm = TRUE) == 1),
         GE = case_when(is.na(GE) & tmp1 == 1 & first(GE) == 0 ~ 0,
                        is.na(GE) & tmp1 == 1 & first(GE) == 1 ~ 1,
                        .default = GE),
         status = case_when(GE == 0 ~ "noinfection",
                            GE == 1 ~ "infection",
                            .default = "mixed")) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-starts_with("tmp"))

fichier
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#       id    vm    GE status     
#    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>      
#  1     2    13     0 noinfection
#  2     2    14     0 noinfection
#  3     2    15     0 noinfection
#  4     2    16     0 noinfection
#  5     2    17     0 noinfection
#  6     2    18     0 noinfection
#  7     2    19     0 noinfection
#  8     2    20     1 infection  
#  9     2    21     0 noinfection
# 10     2    22     1 infection  
# 11     2    23     0 noinfection
# 12     2    24    NA mixed


It's done, have a nice day!

My previous question has not been reopened. So I had to create another question. You can move the answer to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78800544/modify-the-values-of-a-variable

@user25334460 - have added solutions on your new question.
