Modify the values ​of a variable
Attached complete data :
id = c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
vm = c("12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24")
GE = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1","0", "1")
status = c("noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection")
fichier <- data.frame(id, vm, GE, status)

We already have values ​​of the GE variable at visits at 18 and 24 months. Unable to remove them from our dataset. How can I change these values ​​so that they take into account previous visits?
GE = 0 if all previous visits are worth 0.
GE = 1 if at least one of the previous visits is worth 1.

After vm == "18" all GE are "1"?

No, there are vm = 18 and vm = 24. It is necessary that at vm 18 we have the GE values ​​of the previous visits (12 to 17) and that at vm 24 we have the GE values ​​of the previous visits (19 to 23).

A variation of the answer to your previous question, this first changes the 18 and 24 values for vm to NA, then calculates the status column:
Scenario 1:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

id <- c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
vm <- c("12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24")
GE <- c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1","0", "1")
status <- c("noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection")
fichier <- data.frame(id, vm, GE, status)

fichier <- fichier |>
  mutate(across(c(vm, GE), as.integer)) |>
  group_by(id) |> # assuming your data may have multiple id values
  mutate(tmp = if_else(vm <= 18, 1, 2)) |>
  group_by(id, tmp) |>
  mutate(GE = if_else(vm %in% c(18, 24), NA, GE),
         GE = case_when(is.na(GE) & sum(GE, na.rm = TRUE) == 0 ~ 0,
                          is.na(GE) & sum(GE, na.rm = TRUE) > 0 ~ 1,
                          .default = GE),
         status = if_else(GE == 1, "infection", "noinfection")) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-starts_with("tmp"))

fichier
# # A tibble: 13 × 4
#       id    vm    GE status     
#    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>      
#  1     2    12     0 noinfection
#  2     2    13     0 noinfection
#  3     2    14     0 noinfection
#  4     2    15     0 noinfection
#  5     2    16     0 noinfection
#  6     2    17     0 noinfection
#  7     2    18     0 noinfection
#  8     2    19     0 noinfection
#  9     2    20     1 infection  
# 10     2    21     0 noinfection
# 11     2    22     1 infection  
# 12     2    23     0 noinfection
# 13     2    24     1 infection


I don't know how to thank you, I'll see if it works and I'll confirm it !

It works, THANK YOU, have a nice weekend!

Great, that's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for your help!

Here is a solution.
The code below first creates a grouping variable telling if we are in the before "18" and before "24" segments of vm. Then it checks the previous vm values for a 1 and assigns the result to GE.
Also, it is much easier to process numbers so GE is coerced to and from class "integer".
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

id = c (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
vm = c("12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24")
GE = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1","0", "1")
status = c("noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection", "noinfection", "infection")
fichier <- data.frame(id, vm, GE, status)

fichier %>%
  mutate(
    GE = as.integer(GE),
    vm_grp = vm %in% c("18", "24"),
    vm_grp = rev(cumsum(rev(vm_grp)))
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    GE = ifelse(vm %in% c("18", "24"), any(lag(GE, default = 0) == 1), GE),
    GE = as.character(as.integer(GE)),
    .by = c(id, vm_grp)
  ) %>%
  select(-vm_grp)
#>    id vm GE      status
#> 1   2 12  0 noinfection
#> 2   2 13  0 noinfection
#> 3   2 14  0 noinfection
#> 4   2 15  0 noinfection
#> 5   2 16  0 noinfection
#> 6   2 17  0 noinfection
#> 7   2 18  0   infection
#> 8   2 19  0 noinfection
#> 9   2 20  1   infection
#> 10  2 21  0 noinfection
#> 11  2 22  1   infection
#> 12  2 23  0 noinfection
#> 13  2 24  1   infection

Created on 2024-07-27 with reprex v2.1.0

THANK YOU very much for your response, have a good weekend!
